# How to generate HTML file from Excel file, or parse excel graph into python?

Tags: python, html, excel

I have a lot of reports in Excel form, that I want to change into html.

So, I can have live graph. Currently I am using `python jinja2 template` to build the HTML, but I was wondering if there is any other easier way to build HTML from Excel.

Also I want wondering if you can `parse excel graph` into python !

**I tried to:**

Import `pandas` as `pd`

```
file_link = r"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Primire HT ML output testing\Panasonic BR2330 html.xlsx"
data_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_link)
chartAt24C = data_file.parse(sheet_name="VVC")
print(chartAt24C)
```

**It's throwing me error:**

`xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: No sheet named <'VVC'>`

This is the graph I want to parse into python:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While `VVC` is a tab in your Excel workbook, it is not a "sheet". That's why you're getting an error.

Pandas probably can't import graphs but it can import the data that it's built from. You could then use `Pandas`, `matplotlib`, or any other python graphing library to recreate the graph. This would probably only pay off if all your reports are using similar graphs with differing data. But, if all the graphs are designed differently, this would be far too difficult/time-consuming.